# Помогите начать изучать HTML и CSS

Tags: html, css

Я очень мало знаю о вёрстке надеюсь вы мне поможете .

Comment: Посоветуйте мне книги или какие-нибудь курсы , статьи по html и css . (для начинающих) пожалуйста

Comment: как бы вопрос вне тематики ресурса ...

Answer (score 0):

https://htmlacademy.ru/

для начала пройди эти курсы. И потом возвращайся , когда будут вопросы уже технические!) Прочитай условия публикации и цели stackoverflow.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

http://msiter.ru/tutorials/html-nachalnogo-urovnya/uporyadochennye-i-neuporyadochennye-spiski  -- HTML

http://msiter.ru/tutorials/css-nachalnogo-urovnya --- CSS

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1kV2F3MAfE&list=PLQOaTSbfxUtB4yXAyTLvI1QQf8wEEOkl5&index=7

Для начала то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Загляни на youtube, есть много интересного, очень интересный WebDesign Master и Glo Academy. Ребята интересные и подача у них на уровне